# Broken down by year [article]

Tags: articles, indefinite-articles, collocation

With nouns like age or gender, the phrase "Distribution disaggregated by age/gender" sounds fine (at least to me). 
As for the noun "year", which is countable, "disaggregated by year" makes me doubt whether an indefinite article should be used. 
It seems that no article is normally used in the case above, but I would like to understand an explanation of why the article is omitted. 
Is this some sort of a fixed phrase?

Comment: Many nouns have both count and non-count usages, and some which, though non-count as defined by not accepting a numeral, seem to have count affiliation. 'Disaggregated by year' has enough reasonable-looking examples on the internet to strongly suggest idiomaticity, and is modelled on the other examples you give, which are both non-count usages.